# jw player does not work when passing data through variable PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jwplayer

When I pass the data from the URL of the HLS file the player stops working it is as if it did not exist:

```
<?php
    $url = $_GET['player'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Player HLS</title>
    <script src="https://jwpsrv.com/library/FfMxTl3oEeSEiiIACxmInQ.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="aRzklaXf">Loading the player...</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //var urlplay = "https://c6d34z8w3zavhqt3.ezcdn483.net:8443/hls/dcgmsy35q.m3u8?s=qm3aTTYK9EvvG8aHlbOGMg&e=1614565195";
        var urlplay = "<?php echo $url; ?>";
        var playerInstance = jwplayer("aRzklaXf");
        playerInstance.setup({
            //"file": "https://c6d34z8w3zavhqt3.ezcdn483.net:8443/hls/dcgmsy35q.m3u8?s=qm3aTTYK9EvvG8aHlbOGMg&e=1614565195",
            "file": urlplay,
            "height":"560",
            "width":"50%",
            stretching: "bestfit",
            "image": "#",
            "mediaid": "player",
            "mute": false,
            "autostart": false,
            "cast": {
                "appid": "player",
                "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/Tgk2YrC/Logo.png",
            },
        });
    </script>   

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

But if I replace this `var urlplay = "<?php echo $ulr; ?>";` for this `var urlplay = "https://c6d34z8w3zavhqt3.ezcdn483.net:8443/hls/dcgmsy35q.m3u8?s=qm3aTTYK9EvvG8aHlbOGMg&e=1614565195";` it works

Why is it, why does it not work? because it works by adding the route directly and, because not manually using the method used in PHP.

Comment: You are open to XSS injections with this code. `$url` needs to be encoded

Answer (score 0):

I think th culprit is a small typo `$url` vs `$ulr`

(`$url = $_GET['player'];` vs
`var urlplay = "<?php echo $ulr; ?>";`)

:)

Comment: I already corrected that, but it still does not work, I already check the source code the path of the HLS file is added, but it does not work.

Comment: And if you look at the page source, what is the value of `$_GET['player']`?

Comment: This is what does not print me at the end `&e=1614565195` as I do to avoid this `&` cause me that error.

Comment: right... so your filename is a get parameter, but the filename itself contains a get parameters. When you print `$_GET['e']` you'll probably see: "1614565195". Do you have any influence of what is being sent as get parameter? Then you could encode it and decode again, so the get parameters are preserved. Otherwise try setting `<?php
    $url = $_GET['player'].'?e='.$_GET['e'];
?>`

Answer (score 0):

Depends what $_GET['player'] gets you. U need to see what $_GET['player'] is and fill in the url maybe like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //var urlplay = "https://c6d34z8w3zavhqt3.ezcdn483.net:8443/hls/dcgmsy35q.m3u8?s=qm3aTTYK9EvvG8aHlbOGMg&e=1614565195";
    var urlplay = "https://c6d34z8w3zavhqt3.ezcdn483.net:8443/hls/<?php echo $ulr; ?>";
    var playerInstance = jwplayer("aRzklaXf");
    playerInstance.setup({
        //"file": "https://c6d34z8w3zavhqt3.ezcdn483.net:8443/hls/dcgmsy35q.m3u8?s=qm3aTTYK9EvvG8aHlbOGMg&e=1614565195",
        "file": urlplay,
        "height":"560",
        "width":"50%",
        stretching: "bestfit",
        "image": "#",
        "mediaid": "player",
        "mute": false,
        "autostart": false,
        "cast": {
            "appid": "player",
            "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/Tgk2YrC/Logo.png",
        },
    });
</script>
```